# How to remove white space adsense below AdSense ads?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, adsense

I have an AdSense responsive ad unit at the top of a mobile webpage. When a 320x50 ad fills this space, there is extra white space at the bottom of the ad. There is no white space when a 320x100 ad is served. I have not defined a size for the div element, so the unit should adjust to whatever ad Google provides.

Is there a way to collapse the white space if a 320x50 ad is served instead of a 320x100?

I thought this would be a common problem, but I haven't been able to find a solution. Thanks in advance for the help.

I'm thinking that Google initially tries to provide a 320x100 unit, but ultimately provides a 320x50 unit, leaving extra white space. According to Google: "To help increase competition for the 320x100 ad size, we allow 320x50 display ads to appear within this format. When this happens, the smaller ad will always be vertically aligned at the top."

Comment: From what I realize by reading the comment the extra space is reserved for a possible second 320x50 ad. However, can you provide the code? It might be possible to wrap the ad unit inside a 320x50px container with `overflow:hidden` applied on it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My code is below. I tried the overflow suggestion, but it did not change the response. An additional problem is that this div unit does not collapse if Google does not serve an ad unit (even though it is configured to do so). I'm not sure if these problems are related.

Comment: <div align="center">
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Top_Responsive -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxxxx"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

So, since the ad is already inside a container try this:

```
.ad-wrapper {
  width:320px;
  height:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

And add the `ad-wrapper` class on the container.

```
<div class="ad-wrapper" align="center">
  <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
  <!-- Top_Responsive --><ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxx" data-ad-slot="xxxxxxx" data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
  <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});

  </script>
</div>
```

Hope it works!

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but this appears to just force Google to provide an ad unit that is 320x50, as opposed to being 320x100, 320x50, or another ad size (decided by Google). So, this makes the white space go away, but that's because the ad unit is forced to be 320x50. Also, this change makes the ad unit non-responsive, so it does not automatically resize based on the device (i.e. mobile vs. desktop).

Comment: Well it was obvious that this would cause issues. There might be a way to make it responsive but the way it behaves would